# I want to put OR operator in twig if statement but OR operator not working in Twig

Tags: twig

I have written following code but its not working -

```
{% for key, value in data %}
   {% if key == "A" OR key == "A+B" OR key == "A+C" %}
         {% set continue = "false" %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

also tried

```
{% for key, value in data %}
   {% if key == "A" || key == "A+B" || key == "A+C" %}
          {% set continue = "false" %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But its not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try lowercase `or`. But `||` should be working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables initiated inside a loop only live in the scope of that loop. U'd need to define the variable outside the loop in order to access it outside the loop.

```
{% set continue = true %}
{% for key, value in data %}
   {% if key == "A" or key == "A+B" or key == "A+C" %}
         {% set continue = false %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ continue ? 'continue' : 'dont continue' }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/63n6ip)

---

Note: the correct syntax of or in twig is `or`, nothing else.